# Multiplication of numbers of a while-loop in c

Tags: c

If i have a while loop that prints all numbers from 1 to n (e.g. 5) and I want to get a
result = i
, with i being the product of all the numbers between 1 to 5 (120) what would I have to add here?

```
while( i <= n ) {
        printf("%d \n",i);
        i++;
     }
```

I tried
result *= i;
But it didn´t really do anything / just gave me a wrong result

Comment: You would have to declare `result` before the loop and initialize it with `1` and then `result *= i;` in your loops body should work (if `i` is never `0`, or else the result will stay `0`).

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

When you say you want the "product of all the numbers between 1 to 5 (120)," you're talking about mathematical factorial -- expressed (!).

Modifying *your* original code just a little, here is a solution for you -- runnable code is [here](https://godbolt.org/z/v4rKezTbK) and you can see it works.  Note how we added an outer loop so we can run a bunch of numbers for a good test:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int sum, i, runcount =5; 
    
    do{
        sum = 1;   /* reset each run */
        i = runcount;  /* get new number to run factorial against */
        printf("factorial of %d is ", i);
        while(i > 0)
        {
            sum *= i-- ;
        }
        printf("%d \n", sum);
    }while(runcount--);

    return 0;
}
```

Output: -- I encourage you to check these results with a calculator.  It is strange that both 0! *and* 1! = 1, right?  But that's correct.

```
factorial of 5 is 120 
factorial of 4 is 24 
factorial of 3 is 6 
factorial of 2 is 2 
factorial of 1 is 1 
factorial of 0 is 1
```

OK, now let's take this up a notch.  It's traditionally and logically better to make a function of re-usable code, so let's do that.
Our new function will be called factorial().  We'll create it by simply placing selected code from main() into factorial()
and making as few changes as possible, keeping variable names the same where practical for ease of transition:

```
#include <stdio.h>
    
int factorial(int num)
{
    int sum = 1;
    int i = num;  /* get new number to run factorial against */
    while(i > 0)
    {
        sum *= i-- ;
    }
    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    int i, runcount =5; 
    
    do{
        i = runcount;  /* get new number to run factorial against */
        printf("factorial of %d is ", i);
        printf("%d \n", factorial(i));
    }while(runcount--);

    return 0;
}
```

Output: -- is the same and you can check the runnable code [here](https://godbolt.org/z/9anddcdTz)

```
factorial of 5 is 120 
factorial of 4 is 24 
factorial of 3 is 6 
factorial of 2 is 2 
factorial of 1 is 1 
factorial of 0 is 1
```

Let's uplevel this once more and streamline everything with more efficient/good variable naming and usage:

```
#include <stdio.h>
    
int factorial(int num)
{
    int sum = 1;
    while(num > 0)
    {
        sum *= num-- ;
    }
    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    int runcount =5; 
    
    do{
        printf("factorial of %d is %d\n", runcount, factorial(runcount));
    }while(runcount--);

    return 0;
}
```

Output: -- is once again the same and you can check the runnable code [here](https://godbolt.org/z/nojP3K3nd)

```
factorial of 5 is 120 
factorial of 4 is 24 
factorial of 3 is 6 
factorial of 2 is 2 
factorial of 1 is 1 
factorial of 0 is 1
```